# Why do i keep on getting an error with this query?

Tags: sql-server

Find out how many days old each Loan is?
    Find the State with the highest Avg UPB.
        Each Loan has a length of 30 years.  Retrieve the LoanNumber, Attorney Name and the anticipated Finish Date of the Loan.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),LoanDate) AS daysold
FROM [dbo].[Loan]


SELECT STATE AVG(UPB)
FROM [dbo].[Loan]
GROUP BY STATE
HAVING AVG(UPB) = (SELECT MAX(AVG(UPB)) FROM LOAN GROUP BY STATE)
```

Comment: This is not valid MySQL this more looks like SQL Server (MSSQL) because of the  dbo database and brackets.. Well i do know MariaDB has bracket support when running [SQL_MODE=MSSQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-client-software/mariadb-releases/compatibility-differences/sql_modemssql/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix aggregations like `MAX(AVG(UPB))`.
Use this:

```
SELECT STATE, AVG(UPB) 
FROM LOAN 
GROUP BY STATE 
HAVING AVG(UPB) = (
  SELECT TOP (1) AVG(UPB) 
  FROM LOAN 
  GROUP BY STATE
  ORDER BY AVG(UPB) DESC
)
```

For the 1st query to get the difference in days:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, LoanDate, GETDATE()) as daysold
```

Comment: The OP is using NOW() and DATEDIFF with 2 arguments so it may be MySql.

Comment: Well MariaDB can support square brackets when running [SQL_MODE=MSSQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-client-software/mariadb-releases/compatibility-differences/sql_modemssql/)

Comment: *"i see where my error was "* @SQLnewbe please share with the group which of the two queries solved your problem as it might help out others in the future.

Comment: the 2nd query help me out i was mixing the aggregations

Comment: *"the 2nd query help me out i was mixing the aggregations "* @SQLnewbe next time try to tag the correct database system when asking a question it's very important as every RDMS most likely speaks a different SQL dialect

Comment: how do i find out how old each loans are